# "preparing documents" hangs - toctree circular references in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, circular-reference, toctree

i try to generate a documentation with Sphinx but the generation hangs on "preparing documents .." I search for a solution but I don't find any advice to solve the problem.

The problem appears after adding a Table of content to all files.
The structure of the documentation looks like this :

a few Models: Every model has some Tables ( one file per table)
 example:

- Model = AUDITRAIL
- Tables = AUDITTRAIL_BFLOG.rst,  AUDITTRAIL_SESSIONLOG.rst

AUDITRAIL.rst

> ```
> AUDITTRAIL
> ==========
>
> .. toctree::
>    :maxdepth: 1
>
>    AUDITTRAIL_BFLOG.rst
>    AUDITTRAIL_SESSIONLOG.rst
> ```

AUDITTRAIL_SESSIONLOG.rst

> ## AUDITTRAIL.SESSIONLOG
>
> .. toctree::    :maxdepth: 1
>
> AUDITTRAIL.rst
>
> **Keys and indexes**
>
> =====  =====  ====================  seq   type         fields
>   =====  =====  ====================   1        P          SESSIONLOGID       2        I       USRID,SESSIONLOGID 
>   =====  =====  ====================
>
> **Fields**
>
> =====  ====================  =====  =====  ==========  =============== ====================  seq        fieldname        type   inDB   interface    widgettype       description
>   =====  ====================  =====  =====  ==========  =============== ====================   5         CLIENTNAME         S      Y       W20          EDITBOX          Client name        4        COMPUTERNAME        S
>   Y       W20          EDITBOX          Server name        6
>   CREDATIM          E      Y        E8          EDITBOX      Creation
>   date field    11          DESCR            S      Y      W1024
>   EDITBOXLONG     Description field     10          LABEL            S
>   Y       W100         EDITBOX          Label field        1
>   SESSIONLOGID        N      Y       C10          EDITBOX            Id
>   field         8          UPDDATIM          E      Y        E8
>   EDITBOX       Update date field     2           USRID            N
>   Y       C10          EDITBOX            id user          7
>   USRIDCRE          N      Y       C10          EDITBOX      Creation
>   user id field   9          USRIDUPD          N      Y       C10
>   EDITBOX      Update user id field   *3         USR_CODE          S
>   N       W30          EDITBOX                          *
>   =====  ====================  =====  =====  ==========  =============== ====================

I added a table of content on every table file to reference to the other tables from the same model.
I hope somebody can help me.

Greeting,
Mischa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got **circular references** in your documents' TOCs.

`AUDITRAIL.rst` references `AUDITTRAIL_SESSIONLOG.rst` in its TOC, and `AUDITTRAIL_SESSIONLOG.rst` references back to `AUDITTRAIL.rst`. You can't have circular toctree references, you need to remove the `.. toctree::` directive from one file or the other.

Up until 1.1.3 Sphinx failed with a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`, in 1.1.3 this was [changed to ignoring the circular toctree references and printing a warning message](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/851/sphinx-doesnt-notice-circular-tocs-nicely).

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for your answer. How can I solve the problem? I want absolutly show all tables from a model in the Table of content of each table. Thank yout!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to solve this problem. I've been in similar situations and haven't found a solution yet - Sphinx simply can't resolve circular toctree references.